# If $E[Y 1_{\{X \le p \}}]\le 2pk$ where $P[X \ge p]\le k/p$ then $Y $ is a.s. finite?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm not able to follow the stated conclusion below. $Y $ is a nonnegative RV (to be precise it is a sum of the form $\sum_{n \in \mathbb Z }(X_{n+1 } - X_n )^2 $, but I don't think that matter here). I can see that  $P[X \ge p]\le k/p$ means that $X $ is almost surely finite and I also know that $E[Y] < \infty $ implies that $Y $ is almost surely finite (as $ Y $ is nonnegative) - so this is what I would need to show.

> Suppose $E[Y 1_{\{X \le p \}}]\le 2pk$ where $P[X \ge p]\le k/p$ then $Y $ is a.s. finite? How do I show this?

Here $k \geq 0$ is fixed and $p\geq 1$ is any.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are $k$ and $p$  (the range) ?

Comment: $k $ is some nonnegative number and $p $ is some integer greater then or equal to $1 $.

Comment: yes, but for which $k$ and $p$ do you have the inequality ? For instance, is it for any $k=0,1,...$ and any $p \geq 1$, or something else ?

Comment: ah! It is for some $k $ and every $p \ge 1 $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that if $X < +\infty$ a.s., then $Y < \infty$ a.s. follows easily. Indeed, let $A = \{Y = +\infty\}$, we need to show that $\mathbb{P}(A) = 0$. It follows from the condition on $Y$ that 
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y \mathbb{I}_{ \{X \leq p\}} \mathbb{I}_A) \leq  \mathbb{E}(Y \mathbb{I}_{\{X \leq p\}}) <\infty,
$$
hence $Y \mathbb{I}_{X \leq p} \mathbb{I}_A <  \infty$ a.s. meaning that $\mathbb{P}(A \cap \{X \leq p\}) = 0$ for any $p\geq 1$. But since $X < +\infty$ we get $\mathbb{P}(X \leq n ) \to 1 $ as $n\to \infty$, which implies $\mathbb{P}(A) = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \mathbb{P}(A \cap \{X \leq n\})  = 0$, hence the claim.

It remains to show $X < +\infty$ a.s. Observe that $\mathbb{P}(X\geq n^2) \leq \frac{M}{n^2}$ where $M \geq 1$ is a fixed constant and $n=1,2,...$ is any. Now Borel-Cantelli implies that $\mathbb{P}( X \geq n^2 \text{ i. o. } ) = 0 $ and hence $X < +\infty$ a.s.

Comment: Excellent! Though to prove that $X< \infty $ a.s. I would do as follows: $\{X = + \infty \} \subset \cap_p \{X \ge p \} $ and by the continuity of the measure $P $, $P[ \cap_p \{X \ge p \} ]=\lim_p P[\{X \ge p \} ]=0$

Comment: @MrFranzén, I agree, that might be a more natural approach in this case.